# How can I check if I have Thunderbolt x4 or x2?

Tags: thunderbolt, usb-c

I have a Dell XPS 13 on which I have installed Ubuntu. I would like to know if it has PCIe x4 or x2.

Edit 1:
I already know that it is Thunderbolt, just don't know how many PCIe lanes it has.

Edit 2:
This is what I got after trying the suggested command.

```
$ sudo dmidecode | grep PCI
PCI is supported
Type: x16 PCI Express
Type: x1 PCI Express
Type: x1 PCI Express
Type: x1 PCI Express
Type: x1 PCI Express
Type: x1 PCI Express
Type: x1 PCI Express
Type: 32-bit PCI
    SA - PCIe Version
```

Edit 3: After trying, sudo lspci -vv | grep -E 'PCI bridge|LnkCap'

```
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 8GT/s, Width x2, ASPM not supported, Exit Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <16us
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    LnkCap: Port #5, Speed 8GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L1, Exit Latency L0s <1us, L1 <16us
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    LnkCap: Port #6, Speed 8GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L1, Exit Latency L0s <1us, L1 <16us
    LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <64us
    LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type this in a terminal `sudo dmidecode | grep PCI` it will tell you which Pci-e slots you have.

Edit: This should work in an indirect way. Type `sudo lspci -vv | grep -E 'PCI bridge|LnkCap'` in a terminal it should show you something like this:

```
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        LnkCap: Port #247, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
    Capabilities: [b0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
    Capabilities: [b0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s unlimited, L1 unlimited
```

Now just check what version corresponds to the specs you have [here](https://www.eteknix.com/pcie-3-1-and-4-0-specifications-revealed/) and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried that, but I still have no idea if it is x2 or x4. I added the results to the original post. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not home now so the best I can do is link you this: https://superuser.com/questions/693964/can-i-find-out-if-pci-e-slot-is-1-0-2-0-or-3-0-in-linux-terminal since the dmidecode didn't work try following the other solution.

Comment: ok I added another possibility (basically the answer I linked you to but I streamlined it a bit)

Comment: I apologize for not making my question clear initially. I wanted to know if my thunderbolt port has four pcie lanes or two pcie lanes. I did try the command and left the information it showed in my post.

Comment: "LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 8GT/s, Width x2" I'd say 2 lanes